# Django : sort by distance, spatialite does not load C extentions

Tags: python, django, macos, geodjango, spatialite

I want to filter results according to their distance so I used GeoDjango and added a field `PointField` to my model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

location = models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
                                 geography=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True)
```

However, I have this error in my browser when trying to launch the index (my web site)

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. Both SQLite and pysqlite must be configured to allow the loading of extensions to use SpatiaLite.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. Both SQLite and pysqlite must be configured to allow the loading of extensions to use SpatiaLite.
Exception Location: /Users/mac/ostadienv/lib/python3.5/site packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/spatialite/base.py in get_new_connection, line 52
Python Executable:  /Users/mac/ostadienv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.0
```

and this in python:

```
'The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. Both SQLite and pysqlite must be configured to allow the loading of extensions to use SpatiaLite.
```

I'm working on a MAC.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/#mac-os-x-specific-instructions ?

Comment: Yes I did, but it does not work

Comment: When I tape  'brew install geos'  I get this
Warning: geos-3.6.1 already installed, it's just not linked.
are there any relation between them